# contiki: uip_ds6_route_head() vs uip_ds6_route_lookup

Tags: contiki

Can anybody tell me the difference `uip_ds6_route_head()` vs `uip_ds6_route_lookup(addr)`?

I used to think that the `uip_ds6_route_head()` returned a route to every child (direct and indirect) for the node that calls the function. However, two nodes had a route to the same child (the `r->ipaddr == r->nexthop`)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Internally, `uip-ds6-route.c` keeps its routes in a list called `routelist`.

`uip_ds6_route_head()` simply returns the first element in the `routelist`.
`uip_ds6_route_lookup(addr)` will iterate over the `routelist` and return the best matching route for `addr`.

Comment: Thanks, @Ivdoorn! What does the routelist contain?